# Fetching on a background thread - do I have to create a new context?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` to make sure it crashes whenever I do something wrong with Core Data concurrency.

I just wanted to move data loading to the background, so here's the first attempt:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  let context = NSManagedObjectContext.getMainContext() // made up method
  context.fetch(/* ... */)
}
```

Sure enough, this crashes. Makes sense too, we're trying to access the main context from a background thread.

Second attempt:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  let context = NSManagedObjectContext.createPrivateContextAndAssignParent() // made up method
  context.performAndWait {
    context.fetch(/* ... */)
  }
}
```

This works fine! This is also how it should be done, I believe. So there is no real problem, but...

---

**It works also in this case:**

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  NSManagedObjectContext.getMainContext()
  context.performAndWait {
    context.fetch(/* ... */)
  }
}
```

I'm just getting the context for main thread and then accessing it using `prformAndWait` and it works! It's supposed to crash! **Why doesn't it crash?**

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1:**

Whole context:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  let stuff = findStuff()
}

func findStuff() -> NSArray? {
  var stuff: NSArray?
  let context = NSManagedObjectContext.getMainContext()
  context.performAndWait {
    stuff = context.fetch(/* ... */)
  }

  return stuff
}
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome when using `performAndWait`? I would understand if you were using just `perform` but it seems that `performAndWait` is a good fit for your situation, right?

Comment: I'm using `performAndWait` because my function is synchronous and I need it to return the fetched data liket this: (SEE EDIT1 IN ORIGINAL QUESTION)

Comment: Regardless of if you are using `perform` or `performAndWait` the point is that these functions are designed specifically for executing CoreData tasks from a background thread. Why do you expect them to fail if they are executing the provided block on the correct queue?

Comment: I don't understand your third code snippet. You call `NSManagedObjectContext.getMainContext()` but you don't use the result. Where is `context` declared?